# Apache .htaccess <ifModule not allowed here

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

Running Apache on Ubuntu Precise, with PHP 5.5

Trying to access my `var/www/` gives me a 500.

`/var/log/apache2/error.log`

shows:

> `/var/www/web/.htaccess`: `<IfModule>` not allowed here

my `.htaccess` is:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Into my `apache.conf` I added:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride ALL
</Directory>
```

And it worked after I restarted Apache.

Comment: You apparently have full control of your server. You can put the directives directly in the Apache httpd vhost configuration file. (It is a common misconception that redirects HAVE to live in .htaccess. You don't necessarily need .htaccess unless you have no access to the webserver config). https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to configure your apache to enable configuration from the .htaccess file.
So in the directory section   be sure you have the option

```
Allowoverride ALL
```

for more information more information about [allowoverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

In your setup if you use only mod_rewrite maybe you can set only FileInfo , I always set the [Options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#Options) parameter to SymLinksIfOwnerMatch to be able to perform redirection to other sites.

```
Allowoverride FileInfo 
Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

I hope it will help, if you already set this configuration please add information with your virtualhost configuration.

Comment: This is a fresh install of Apache. I have no <Directory /> section in apache2.conf. I've added my update above. Thanks

Comment: I forgot to restart Apache. Thats working now .

Comment: On my end I had a missing `Directory` directive. Once added, it worked properly. I suppose this is new in version 2.4 of Apache because it used to work with 2.2...

Comment: Yes, the default value for Allowedoverride changed in Apache 2.3.9.